# How to force Shake to echo stdout from scripts?

Tags: stdout, output-buffering, shake-build-system

I'm using [Shake](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake) to manage some scripts that might run a really long time (days or even weeks). They print their progress to stdout using the [progressbar](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar) Python module. How can I make Shake echo that progress during the run, rather than just showing the "100%" state at the end?

Things I've tried:

- changing `shakeVerbosity` and also set some other options like `shakeCommandOptions = [EchoStdout True]` and `shakeLineBuffering = False`
- adding `stdout.flush()` calls to the scripts

UPDATE: If I just print to stdout rather than using the progress bar, that works. So maybe it has to do with line buffering? The progressbar probably doesn't print a newline until the end.

Comment: It's almost certainly down to line buffering. Are you able to try out the HEAD version of Shake? I just pushed something I think might help. Note that if you are running long-running commands, and they output their progress to stderr (I rather suspect they will be), then make sure you set WithStderr False.

Comment: It almost compiles but right at the end I get:

    In-place registering shake-0.15.8...
    Preprocessing executable 'shake' for shake-0.15.8...
    ghc: unrecognised flag: -qg
    did you mean one of:
      -g
    unrecognised flag: -qb

    Usage: For basic information, try the `--help' option.

Comment: It's also not that big a deal if I can't solve this, because I haven't tried doing it the "right way" yet with Shake's progress features.

Comment: Which `ghc --version` are you using?

Comment: 7.10.3, but I'm on NixOS so I can try a different one if that helps. I think the newest is 8.0.1 as of a couple days ago

Comment: Both should work. I released a new version of Shake earlier today which should have the fix it in, so waiting for Nix to pick that up might be one option.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue is fixed in the latest version of Shake, so should no longer occur (as of Jun 2016).